# Can we make JsonTypeName optional?

Tags: java, jackson

I am dealing with a class which is defined this way:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeName("classA")
public class A implements B {
    private String name;
    private List<String> list;

    public A(String name, List<String> list) {
        this.name = name;
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

And class B is defined this way:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = C.class, name = "classC"),
@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = A.class, name = "classA")})

public interface B {
    public String getName();
}
```

I want to deserialize an InputStream this way:

```
objectMapper.readValue(stream, A.class)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'type' that is to contain type id  (for class A)
```

Now, I do understand that I can 'inject' the type property but the problem is that the stream is really huge I can't afford to convert it to a string and then manipulate it.

What are my options here?

PS: This class is using lombok for getters, setters and default constructor.

Comment: what does your json look like?

Comment: It looks like this: {"name":"dummyName","list":["list1","list2"]}

Comment: If you are talking about missing getter and setter, then this class uses lombok annotations for that. Sorry, I did not mention it.

Comment: i checked it worked, what are you still missing?

Comment: Well the only thing that I left out was the definition of the interface B. I have added that too.